# Validating dates from a file that is redirected as input

Tags: c, validation, date, file-handling, stdio

First and foremost, this is a homework question.

A file with a list of dates in the format of mm/dd/yyyy are to be redirected as input from the command prompt. Here is an example ./main.out < file.txt. For every single valid date that I find, I'm suppose to write it to an output file.

---

My professor has given a criteria on what constitutes an invalid date.

**1.)** if there are any non numeric characters like 12/4A/199A5.

**2.)** if they are missing their forward slashes or have more than 2 forward slashes.

**3.)** if they are floating points like 12/4/1995.3

**4.)** if they are incorrect dates like 2/29/1973 because 29 means that the year is suppose to be a leap year but 1973 is not divisible by 4 or 400.

**5.)** if there is no date(empty string) or parts of it are missing like 4/3/.

---

Here examples of valid dates.

**1.)** dates with leading or trailing white-spaces like 12 /23/  1694

**2.)** dates with leading zeros like 004/030/2000

**3.)** Any date with with month number between 1 and 12, correct day length(this depends on the month) and the year can be a positive number, negative or zero.

---

Here is what I have done so far with only the relevant functions that are necessary.

```
int writeToFile()
{
    FILE *outputFile;
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    int month = 0, days = 0, year = 0;
    int isValidFormat = 0, isValidDate = 0;
    size_t strDateLength;

    outputFile = fopen("Output.dat", "w");

    if(outputFile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't write to the file.\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin))
    {
        strDateLength = strlen(buffer);

        if(buffer[strDateLength - 1] != '\n' && strDateLength <  BUFFERSIZE - 1)
        {
            appendNewLine(buffer, strDateLength);
        }

        isValidFormat = validateDateFormat(buffer, &month, &days, &year, strDateLength);

        if(isValidFormat)
        {
            isValidDate = validateDate(month, days, year);

            if(isValidDate)
            {
                fprintf(outputFile, "%s", buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(outputFile);
    return TRUE;
}

void appendNewLine(char *str, size_t strLength)
{
    str[strLength] = '\n';
    str[strLength + 1] = '\0';
}

int validateDateFormat(char *str, int *month, int *days, int *year, size_t strDateLength)
{
    int index, index2 = 0;
    char temp[BUFFERSIZE];
    int numOfForwSlashes = 0;

    for(index = 0; index < strDateLength; index++)
    {
        if(str[index] == '/')
        {
            if(numOfForwSlashes == 0)
            {
                *month = atoi(temp);
            }
            else if(numOfForwSlashes == 1)
            {
                *days = atoi(temp);
            }

            numOfForwSlashes++;
            memset(&temp[0], 0, sizeof(temp));
            index2 = 0;
        }
        else if(str[index] == '\n')
        {
            *year = atoi(temp);
        }
        else if(!isdigit(str[index]) && str[index] != ' ')
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[index2] = str[index];
            index2++;
        }
    }

    if(numOfForwSlashes != TOTALFORWARDSLASHES) // This define is 2
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
        return TRUE;
}

int validateDate(int month, int days, int year)
{
    if((month < JANUARY || month > DECEMBER) && (days < 1 || days > THIRTYONE))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(month == FEBURARY)
    {
        if(isLeapYear(year))
        {
            if(days > TWENTYNINE)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(days > TWENTYEIGHT)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(month == APRIL || month == JUNE || month == SEPTEMBER || month == NOVEMBER)
    {
        if(days > THIRTY)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(days > THIRTYONE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

**Problem:**

For the most part it works except for cases where the year is missing and to be frank I would like to know if there is way I could make this more concise while still following the citeria. Using sscanf or scanf doesn't solve every problem I have nor does string functions like strtok help that much.

Comment: "Couldn't write to the file" is the canonical example of a bad error message. `fp = fopen(path, "w"); if( fp == NULL) { perror(path); ...`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... it works except for cases where the year is missing and to be frank I would like to know if there is way I could make this more concise ...

Rather than make only a single function to parse the date, create a helper function to parse each integer.

Untested code sample:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Parse 1 int and optional following delimiter
// Return NULL on error
static const char *Get_int(const char *p, int *i, int endchar) {
  if (p) {
    char *endptr;
    errno = 0;
    long y = strtol(p, &endptr, 10);
    if (errno || p == endptr) return NULL;
    *i = y;  // Test for INT_MIN... INT_MAX if desired

    // skip following white-space
    while (isspace((unsigned char ) *endptr))
      endptr++;

    // Look for delimiter
    if (endchar) {
      if (*endptr != endchar) return NULL;
      endptr++;
    }
    return endptr;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int validateDateFormat(char *str, int *month, int *days, int *year, 
    size_t strDateLength) {
  // form string
  char temp[strDateLength + 1];
  memcpy(temp, str, strDateLength);
  temp[strDateLength] = '\0';
  const char *p = temp;

  p = Get_int(p, month, '/');
  p = Get_int(p, days, '/');
  p = Get_int(p, year, 0);
  return p && *p == '\0';
}
```

A `sscanf()` approach:

Use `"%n"` to detect if entire string was scanned.

```
int validateDateFormat(char *str, int *month, int *days, int *year, 
    size_t strDateLength) {
  // form string
  char temp[strDateLength + 1];
  memcpy(temp, str, strDateLength);
  temp[strDateLength] = '\0';

  int n = 0;
  sscanf(temp, "%d /%d /%d %n", month, days, year, &n);
  return n > 0 && temp[n] == '\0';
)
```

---

Hacker exploit: Notice that the below code assumes `strDateLength > 0`.  `fgets()` will happily read in as the first character the null character and continue reading until a `'\n'` is encountered.

As `strDateLength` is a `size_t`, an unsigned type, `0-1` is a huge value and `buffer[strDateLength - 1]` will certainly cause problems.

```
while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)) {
  strDateLength = strlen(buffer);
  if(buffer[strDateLength - 1] != ...
```

BTW, no real need to add `'\n'` anyways.

Comment: @Luis Averhoff "Couldn't you have done `const char *p = str;`' --> Only if `str` points to a _string_.  If it points to a _string_, there is not need for the `size_t strDateLength`.  Seeing `size_t strDateLength` in the function signature implies to me that `char *str` may only point to a a character array and not to a _string_.

Comment: @Luis Averhoff The rest is for you to clean-up